# Silverlight: Adding ChangePropertyAction to DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight

I was playing around, experimenting and googling this for the last hour and cannot figure out the problem. Basically, I have a listbox, each item has textblock and checkbox. I need to change text of textblock to green next to the checked checkbox. The code below is the best that I could come up with, but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
        <Grid
            Width="80">
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="textBlock"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Text="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource DataConverter}}"
                Foreground="#FF859FAF"
                FontSize="12"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Width="50"
                Margin="0"
                Grid.Row="10" />
            <CheckBox
                x:Name="Btn6"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Cursor="Hand"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Height="32"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                Width="26"
                d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger
                        EventName="textBlock">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                            TargetName="textBlock"
                            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}"
                            PropertyName="Width"
                            Value="100">
                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding SelectDataCommand, Source={StaticResource ControlViewModel}}"
                            CommandName="SelectDateRangeCommand"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </CheckBox>
```

Comment: (sorry for my bad english) - this do not answer your question but an easy alternative would be to bind `IsSelected` with the `TextBox.Foreground` and create a converter that return a `SolidColorBrush` green when the value is true.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do it. Why did you put it as comment and not answer?

Comment: I added as a comment because it did not directly address your question... but since it helped, I posted as an answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

This do not exactly answer your question but an easy alternative would be to bind `IsSelected` with the `TextBox.Foreground` and create a converter that return a `SolidColorBrush` green when the value is true